# Python OpenCv can open external webcam but can't show image

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I'm trying to read and image from VideoCapture from an external webcam on my mac, but I'm not able to display the image. Here what I'm using:

- Python: 3.9.1
- opencv-contrib-python: 4.5.1.48
- MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3
- External webcam: Logitech C905

I'm running the script from the command line, and I'm pretty sure that I gave all the permissions needed. Everything is working fine on my friend's laptop using Linux. I'm able to see the webcam image when i'm using FaceTime or Photo Booth.

Here's the code:

```html
class Camera:
    def __init__(self, camera_index: int):
        self._camera_index = camera_index
        self._capture = None
        self._open_capture()

    def take_world_image(self):
        return self._get_camera_frame()

    def _get_camera_frame(self):
        print(self._capture.read)
        opened_successfully, current_frame = self._capture.read()
        if not opened_successfully:
            raise InvalidCameraConfigException
        return current_frame

    def _open_capture(self):
        self._capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self._camera_index)
        
    def _close_capture(self):
        self._capture.release()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    camera = Camera(1)
    while True:
        image = camera.take_world_image()
        cv2.imshow("image", image)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

open_successfully return True, but this is the image I'm getting:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL488.png)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If your code works with main webcam and on linux, that the problem is on Mac permission, not python.

Try instead of running the script on an iDE open it up Terminal on Mac into the folder that contained .py file and run it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm getting the same result when I'm running the code from the Terminal or Pycharm. In System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Camera, both Terminal and Pycharm have the permission to access the camera. I'm trying to see if the permission for external camera is different, but I don't have a lot of success right now. If it is possible, do you know how to do it?

Comment: Try cv2.VideoCapture(self._camera_index) with this values cv2.VideoCapture(0) or cv2.VideoCapture(1) or cv2.VideoCapture(2) and Check!

Comment: Hi Freddy, thank you for the suggestion.I tried, works fine with the built-in camera, index 2 is out of range (as expected) but I still have the same problem with index 1 (the external camera).

Comment: Try to uninstall the camera drivers and install again.